# Filter for message collector that would find a specific text on a message.content, discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have this filter and array for a message collector.

```
const answers = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];   
const filter = msg => answers.includes(msg.content());
```

That filter only detects a content that exactly matches what's in the array. So if a message say, "Scissors!!", it isn't detected because of the extra text (!!). The design is it should still be detected.

Is it correct that I should use a for loop with the filter? How do I exactly do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple. You can use the `.some()` function which will return `true` if the condition passed in the callback matches for any of the values and will return `false` if otherwise. An example:

```js
const string = "test!!";
const answers = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

console.log(answers.some((val) => string.includes(val.toLowerCase())));
```